# git : automatic action after successful merge on master

Tags: python, git, distutils

I need to build an egg, using `python setup.py bdist_egg`, after each successful merge to master. Can this be performed automatically by git ?
Thank you !

Comment: Why make *git* do that? Do you have any CI/CD automation where you could build that?

Comment: I am not sure that screwdriver has 'python' command available. Is there a way to build the egg using only system commands ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Screwdriver, but if Python isn't available how is it doing any of the rest of your build?

Comment: Currently : copy-paste each py files for a pyspark application. There is no 'build' to be done. I am trying to move from individual modules to package.